# Cant Call a method from another class in java

Tags: java, android

I have a class loadDAta() which contains a method to get the json from the server say loadData(String url). i am calling this according to the option items

```
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.Date;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class loadDAta{
        private AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();

public void loadDatas(String url) {

    client.post(url, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            try {
               int st = response.getInt("st");
               int timest = response.getInt("t");
               Date dateTime = new Date(timest);
               String dateString = (String) DateFormat.format("dd:MM:yyyy \t\t  hh:mm:ss", dateTime);
               double val = response.getDouble("v");
                Data data=new Data();
                data.setDate(dateString);
                data.setValue(val);
                data.setState(st);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

I am setting those values in another class called Data()

```
public class Data {
private String date,url;
private double value;
private int state;


public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public double getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(double value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public int getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(int state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public String getURL() {
    return url;
}

public void setURL(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
```

}

the operation inside the loadData() method is not performing when i called like this from another class

```
loadDAta lds=new loadDAta();
        lds.loadDatas(myUrl);

 Data dat=new Data();
    date1=dat.getDate();
    val=dat.getValue();
    st=dat.getState();
```

then the value getting here is, when it Is string then nothing, when it is int then 0 , and when it Is double then 0.0

is there any problem in my code against that method call....

Comment: On a side note, `loadDAta` is a terrible name for a class.That's something you'd name a method.Plus, class names should (by convention) start with a capital letter.

Comment: Tyring printing something from loadDatas

Comment: I tried it by calling the set methods with fixed values..from loadDatas()...

Comment: Your `onSuccess` method is populating a local `Data` object and then discarding it.  If you want the same object, you have to hang on to a reference to it, you can't just create a new (different) instance of `Data` and expect it to hold the same state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rename the class `loadDAta` (sic) to `DataLoader`. If you name the class for the main job of the class, there is never any confusion for you (or other developers!).

Also, the reason you are not receiving the correct variable information is because in `onSuccess()` in `loadDatas(String url)`, you are initializing a new `Data` with `Data data=new Data();` (for this, let's think of an instance as a variable container). You then set the data *but you do nothing with your instance!* You let the instance of `Data` die, and with it, your variables die.

You then try to `Data data=new Data();` again at the end, which spawns a new, clean, empty `Data` instance. This instance knows nothing of the data you passed its brother in the above call, because they are different instances.

To achieve what you'd like, you will need to pass the fully initialized `Data` object to where you need the variables.

For example:

```
Data data = new Data();
data.setDate(dateString);
System.out.println(data.getDate()); //THIS WILL PRINT dateString CORRECTLY


Data data2 = new Data();
System.out.println(data2.getDate()); //THIS WILL NOT, BECAUSE THIS INSTANCE DOES NOT HAVE THE date VARIABLE SET!!!
```

Now that you hopefully understand why this has happened, let's go about a fix. The most elegant solution would be to allow `loadDatas()` to return an instantiated `Data` object, like so:

```
public Data loadDatas(String url) {
    final Data data = new Data();
    client.post(url, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
        super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            try  {
                int st = response.getInt("st");
                int timest = response.getInt("t");
                Date dateTime = new Date(timest);
                String dateString = (String) DateFormat.format("dd:MM:yyyy \t\t  hh:mm:ss", dateTime);
                double val = response.getDouble("v");
                data.setDate(dateString);
                data.setValue(val);
                data.setState(st);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

Then we can call `Data data = DataLoader.loadDatas(String)`, and `data` will contain the expected information you'll need.

For a better understanding, I suggest reading the official Oracle docs, [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Happy coding! :)

Comment: it shows a nullpointerexception then.......' Data dat = lds.loadDatas(url);
        date1=dat.getDate();<<here'

Comment: Did you change `Data data = new Data();`, to just `data = new Data();` like I have  in my snippet?

Comment: @noushad_chullian, Try my edit. I've moved the instantiation of `data` to the outer method, and declared it `final` to allow access to the inner method. Sorry, I'm doing this from my head, without a compiler :) Most importantly, do you understand what your problem was? As the adage goes, "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: the data is not getting     **Data dat = lds.loadDatas(url); date1=dat.getDate();'**<<here

Comment: @noushad_chullian, What is it telling you? Have you tried printing `dateString` prior to `setDate()`to ensure your data is sane? Are you sure `onSuccess()` is even called? The call may fail, and you do not have a failure callback overriden for your anonymous `JsonHttpResponseHandler` (in the code you've posted).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have a problem.

```
Data dat=new Data();
```

Here you are creating a new `Data` object and hence all fields in this object is empty. Instead do the below:

```
loadDAta lds=new loadDAta();
Data dat = lds.loadDatas(myUrl);
    date1=dat.getDate();
    val=dat.getValue();
    st=dat.getState();
```

Now this will work. Make sure that the `loadDatas()` method returns a `Data` object.